# How to fix spaces in column names of a data.frame (remove spaces, inject dots)?

Tags: r, dataframe

After importing a file, I always try try to remove spaces from the column names to make referral to column names easier.

Is there a better way to do this other then using transform and then removing the extra column this command creates?

This is what I use now:

```
names(ctm2)
#tranform function does this, but requires some action
ctm2<-transform(ctm2,dymmyvar=1)
#remove dummy column
ctm2$dymmyvar <- NULL
names(ctm2)
```

Comment: Use the inject.dots function: `inject.dots <- function(df) {names(df) <- sub(" ", ".", names(df));df}`

Comment: On a serious side I'm surprised R imports in column names with spaces and doesn't fix it automatically.

Comment: @TylerRinker The read.table function does that by default with the `make.names` function.

Comment: @TylerRinker: yes it does. Both `read.csv/read.table(..., check.names=T)`. And the default is TRUE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UDPDATE 2022 Aug:

```
df %>% rename_with(make.names)
```

OLD code was: (still works though)
as of Jan 2021: drplyr solution that is brief and uses no extra libraries is

```
df %<>% dplyr::rename_all(make.names)
```

credit goes to commenter.

Comment: [rename_all](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select_all.html) has been superseded by  [rename_with](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rename.html) -- though this solution will certainly work as is.

Answer (score 85):

There exists more elegant and general solution for that purpose:

```
tidy.name.vector <- make.names(name.vector, unique=TRUE)
```

`make.names()` makes syntactically valid names out of character vectors. A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed by a number.

Additionally, flag `unique=TRUE` allows you to avoid possible dublicates in new column names.

As code to implement

```
d<-read_delim(urltxt,delim='\t',)
names(d)<-make.names(names(d),unique = TRUE)
```

Comment: grate solution. Here a tidy alternative:
`df %>% dplyr::rename_all(funs(make.names(.)))`

Comment: funs() is soft-deprecated as of `dplyr 0.8.0` so a tidy alternative would now be: `df %>% dplyr::rename_all(list(~make.names(.)))`

Comment: `df %>% rename_all(make.names)`

Comment: `rename_all()` is superseded in `dplyr 1.0.7.` so it would be better to use `df %>% rename_with(make.names)`

Answer (score 50):

There is a very useful package for that, called `janitor` that makes cleaning up column names very simple. It removes all unique characters and replaces spaces with `_`.

```
library(janitor)

#can be done by simply
ctm2 <- clean_names(ctm2)

#or piping through `dplyr`
ctm2 <- ctm2 %>%
        clean_names()
```

Answer (score 39):

To replace only the first space in each column you could also do:

```
names(ctm2) <- sub(" ", ".", names(ctm2))
```

or to replace all spaces (which seems like it would be a little more useful):

```
names(ctm2) <- gsub(" ", "_", names(ctm2))
```

or, as mentioned in the first answer (though not in a way that would fix all spaces):

```
spaceless <- function(x) {colnames(x) <- gsub(" ", "_", colnames(x));x}
newDF <- spaceless(ctm2)
```

where x is the name of your data.frame.  I prefer to use "_" to avoid issues with "." as part of an ID.

The point is that gsub doesn't stop at the first instance of a pattern match.

Comment: The problem with this, at least on my end, is: If a column name has more than one space, it will only replace the first

Answer (score 14):

`dplyr::select_all()` can be used to reformat column names. This example replaces spaces and periods with an underscore and converts everything to lower case:

```
iris %>%  
  select_all(~gsub("\\s+|\\.", "_", .)) %>% 
  select_all(tolower) %>% 
  head(2)
  sepal_length sepal_width petal_length petal_width species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Answer (score 12):

Assign the names like this. This works best. It replaces all white spaces in the name with underscore.

`names(ctm2)<-gsub("\\s","_",names(ctm2))`

Comment: The most direct, most concise solution, by far.

Answer (score 11):

best solution I found so far is

```
names(ctm2) %<>% stringr::str_replace_all("\\s","_") %>% tolower
```

credit goes to commenters and other answers

Comment: Is there a way to integrate this into an apply-type function in order to rename columns in multiple datasets?

Answer (score 9):

It's often convenient to change the names of your columns within one chunk of `dplyr` code rather than renaming the columns after you've created the data frame. Piping in `rename_all()` is very useful in these situations:

```
ctm2 %>% rename_all(function(x) gsub(" ", "_", x))
```

The code above will replace all spaces in every column name with an underscore.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you may be able to achieve the same results with the `stringr` package.

`names(ctm2) <- names(ctm2) %>% stringr::str_replace_all("\\s","_")`

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy way to remove spaces in column names in data.table. You will have to convert your data frame to data table.

```
setnames(x=DT, old=names(DT), new=gsub(" ","",names(DT)))
```

`Country Code` will be converted to `CountryCode`

Comment: Omit `old` and it will have the same result. (This is covered in the docs.)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use combination of make names and gsub functions in R.

```
names(ctm2)<- gsub("\\.","_", make.names(names(ctm2), unique = T))
```

Above code will do 2 things at a time:

1. It will create unique names for all columns - for e.g. same names will be converted to unique e.g. c("ab","ab") will be converted to c("ab","ab2")
2. It will replace dots with Underscores. it becomes easy (just double click on name) when you try to select column name which has underscore as compared to column names with dots. selecting column names with dots is very difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Just assign to `names(ctm2)`:

```
  names(ctm2) <- c("itsy", "bitsy", "eeny", "meeny")
```

or in data-driven way:

```
  names(ctm2) <- paste("myColumn", 1:ncol(ctm2), sep="")
```

Another possibility is to edit your source file...

Answer (score 0):

If you use read.csv() to import your data (which replaces all spaces " " with ".") you can replace these instead with an underscore "_" using:

```
names(df) <- gsub("\\.", "_", names(df))
```