# Binding dataframes with matching country names

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, match

I have two data frames of country data.
`df1` has all the countries of the world.
`df2` has a subset of countries but has the populations in one of its columns.
I want to take the population data and add it to `df1` where the country names are a match.

If `df1$Column1 = df2$Column1` (same country name) then populate `df1$Column2` (currently empty) with the information from `df2$Column2` (country's population) where the row is the the one for that country match.

I tried to merge the two using the column "Name" which they both have for country names :

```
total <- merge(map,Co2_2x, by="NAME")
```

the columns are all there but I get empty rows in my new dataframe.

I'd like to be able to say "for this row and column matrix position in df1 (the country), get the row (country name match in `df2`) and column X (population data). Then put it in this row and column Y matrix position in `df1` (new population column in `df1` for the matched country name)"... There must be an easier way :-)

Here is my code : I'd like to fill `map$measure` with data from `Co2_2x$premium` where the countries match.

```
library(XML)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
download.file("http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip",destfile="TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip")
unzip("TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip",exdir=getwd())
polygons <- shapefile("TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp")

polygons
map <- as.data.frame(polygons)

map$Measure  <- 0

library(rvest)
Co2 <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_carbon_dioxide_emissions")

Co2_2x<-Co2  %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  html_table()

names(Co2_2x)[2]<-paste("premium")

names(Co2_2x)[1]<-paste("NAME")


total <- merge(map,Co2_2x, by="NAME")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Peter, welcome to SO. What did you try to address your issue ? We must know that to give proper advises.

Comment: Hi Vincent,  I tried to merge the two using the column "Name" which they both have for country names. total <- merge(map,Co2_2x, by="NAME")    But I get empty rows in my new dataframe but the columns are all there.

Comment: Ok. Can you please, do explain that in your question rather than in the commentary ?

Comment: Thanks, your question is much better already ! What we do like too is that you provide some code summarizing your data (`df1<-data.frame(...)`). That way, we are able to run directly your code, see what exactly happens and find the solution much quicker. Also, don't forget to use codeblocks when you provide code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the first dataset rows with no match in the other dataset appear, you just need to add the `all.x=T` option, as follows (have a look at [the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) for details) :

```
total <- merge(map,Co2_2x, by="NAME",all.x=T)
```

These rows will then appear with `NA` in the second dataset columns.

If the matching doesn't seem to work, you may want to make sure that your matching variable (in your case, `NAME`) is filled exaclty the same way in the two datasets (letter case, possible spaces at the extremities...).
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688137/how-to-fix-spaces-in-column-names-of-a-data-frame-remove-spaces-inject-dots/25153553#25153553) provides a fine way of doing so.

Comment: Thanks. That worked a bit. I get the columns added but all their data is "NA" in every field.

Comment: I wish I could download the proper table... But with the test DF I used, the `NA` occur only when there is no match for `df1`'s x value in `df2`. Are you sure the two name columns really match ? There could be spaces at the end of one for example ?

Comment: Yes!  One has "China"  the other has " China" with a space.  :-)

Comment: Great ! I guess you got rid of those one way or another, but you might want to have a look at this elegant way of doing so : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688137/how-to-fix-spaces-in-column-names-of-a-data-frame-remove-spaces-inject-dots

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sqldf` library in R.

Just follow the code below. You'll be able to merge (join) the two dataset that you have:

```
library(sqldf)
merged_data <- sqldf("select a.country, b.population from df1 as a 
                     left join df2 as b on (a.country = b.country) group by 1")
```

Thanks and happy R-programming!!!

Comment: > merged_data <- sqldf("select map.NAME, Co2_2x.premium from map as a  left join Co2_2x as NAME on (map.NAME = Co2_2x.NAME) group by 1")
Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: no such column: map.NAME

Comment: My df "map" has a column called "NAME".  They both have it as the column with country names...  Did I do something else wrong?

Comment: I tried this and got the column added but all the items in the column are "NA": library(sqldf)
merged_data <- sqldf("select map.* 
                      ,Co2_2x.premium 
                      from map 
                      left join Co2_2x 
                      on map.NAME = Co2_2x.NAME")

Comment: @PeterNsanze your SQL query is wrong...i am pasting the correct one...

`sqldf("select a.NAME, b.premium from map as a left join Co2_2x as b on (a.NAME = b.NAME) group by 1")`