# Time series of counts of records with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have a series of records of events (in this case deaths). They are now in a data frame, with one column containing the date as class Date and other columns containing details as factors (e.g. where the death occurred). They records are sorted into data order.

I am trying to use `ggplot` to plot time series of the numbers of deaths. But I get various error messages with different approaches. I thought the minimum that would create a bar chart of numbers of deaths by date would be something like:

```
F1 <- ggplot(DeathsSorted.df, aes('Date of death'))
F1 + geom_bar()
```

But all that produces is a greyed out block with no bars.

What's worse is that this code seemed to work before I updated to the latest version of *R Studio* and *R*.

Comment: Could you please add an example of your data to your post? That makes it easier to help you.

Comment: Hard to do, as some of it is confidential (i.e. the first column). class returns data frame for the object DeathsSorted.df and  the column Date of death reads: Date of death : Date, format: "2016-04-01, "2016-04-01". Hope that helps.

Comment: class(DeathSorted.df$'Date of death') returns [1] "Date"

Comment: Before I updated R Studio very recently to version 1.0.153, when I imported the date, the column of the csv file imported had the column name 'Date.of.death', but since the update it comes in with spaces 'Date of death'.  That was when these ggplot commands seemed to stop working. Not sure whether that has any relevance.

Comment: You need to use backticks for non-syntactic names, not single quote.

Answer (score 3):

This works fine:

```
df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(c("2017-09-08","2017-09-09","2017-09-08",
        "2017-09-10","2017-09-08","2017-09-10","2017-09-01","2017-09-11")) )


F1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=date))
F1 + geom_bar()
```

You just had a typo; date should not between quotes.

Next time, post some fake data (like my `df`), so people can help you better/more easily.

Comment: So, I must have to rename all column names that R Studio has spaces in otherwise I get another error about unrecognised character in the name? There doesn't seem to be any option to remove them on importing the data.

Comment: I have the same version of R Studio and if I use a column name with spaces, it's still converted to dots and I can use the same code as given in my answer.

Comment: OK. Mine doesn't it now leaves spaces. Thanks so much for the help. I'll try to sort.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688137/how-to-fix-spaces-in-column-names-of-a-data-frame-remove-spaces-inject-dots