# Remove automatically all spaces from column names using read_excel

Tags: r, readxl

The column names in my .xlsx Excel sheet have spaces. How can I automatically replace the spaces with "_" or "."? I would like to use `read_excel` because I need to specify a range in my excel sheet.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688137/how-to-fix-spaces-in-column-names-of-a-data-frame-remove-spaces-inject-dots) may be helpful.

Comment: In `read_excel()` use the `.name_repair` argument. E.g., `.name_repair = "universal"`, or create a function to do exactly what you want. See `?tibble::tibble` for more info on the `.name_repair` argument.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to do it using the `.name_repair` argument with `read_excel()`:

**Creating the excel file for import**:

```
# Example setup
mtcars = datasets::mtcars
names(mtcars) = paste(names(mtcars), LETTERS[1:length(mtcars)])
head(mtcars)
                  mpg A cyl B disp C hp D drat E  wt F qsec G vs H am I gear J carb K
Mazda RX4          21.0     6    160  110   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4
Mazda RX4 Wag      21.0     6    160  110   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4
Datsun 710         22.8     4    108   93   3.85 2.320  18.61    1    1      4      1
Hornet 4 Drive     21.4     6    258  110   3.08 3.215  19.44    1    0      3      1
Hornet Sportabout  18.7     8    360  175   3.15 3.440  17.02    0    0      3      2
Valiant            18.1     6    225  105   2.76 3.460  20.22    1    0      3      1

temp = tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")
writexl::write_xlsx(mtcars, temp)
```

**Reading in the data several different ways**:

```
# With using the default for .name_repair ("unique" for read_excel())
head(readxl::read_excel(temp))
# A tibble: 6 x 11
  `mpg A` `cyl B` `disp C` `hp D` `drat E` `wt F` `qsec G` `vs H` `am I` `gear J` `carb K`
    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1    21         6      160    110     3.9    2.62     16.5      0      1        4        4
2    21         6      160    110     3.9    2.88     17.0      0      1        4        4
3    22.8       4      108     93     3.85   2.32     18.6      1      1        4        1
4    21.4       6      258    110     3.08   3.22     19.4      1      0        3        1
5    18.7       8      360    175     3.15   3.44     17.0      0      0        3        2
6    18.1       6      225    105     2.76   3.46     20.2      1      0        3        1


# Adding periods using using .name_repair
head(readxl::read_excel(temp, .name_repair = "universal"))
# A tibble: 6 x 11
  mpg.A cyl.B disp.C  hp.D drat.E  wt.F qsec.G  vs.H  am.I gear.J carb.K
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1  21       6    160   110   3.9   2.62   16.5     0     1      4      4
2  21       6    160   110   3.9   2.88   17.0     0     1      4      4
3  22.8     4    108    93   3.85  2.32   18.6     1     1      4      1
4  21.4     6    258   110   3.08  3.22   19.4     1     0      3      1
5  18.7     8    360   175   3.15  3.44   17.0     0     0      3      2
6  18.1     6    225   105   2.76  3.46   20.2     1     0      3      1

# Using a custom function to add underscores
head(readxl::read_excel(temp, .name_repair = function(x) gsub("\\s+", "_", x)))
# A tibble: 6 x 11
  mpg_A cyl_B disp_C  hp_D drat_E  wt_F qsec_G  vs_H  am_I gear_J carb_K
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1  21       6    160   110   3.9   2.62   16.5     0     1      4      4
2  21       6    160   110   3.9   2.88   17.0     0     1      4      4
3  22.8     4    108    93   3.85  2.32   18.6     1     1      4      1
4  21.4     6    258   110   3.08  3.22   19.4     1     0      3      1
5  18.7     8    360   175   3.15  3.44   17.0     0     0      3      2
6  18.1     6    225   105   2.76  3.46   20.2     1     0      3      1

# file.remove(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not way to tell it to do that in the method `read_excel()` however you can do two things to circumvent the problem.

```
#create list of column names as you wish them to appear manually
names_vector<- c("name-1", "name_2"....)

#set the col_names argument equal to the list of names
data<-read_excel( <file_name>, col_names =names_vector)
```

These two steps will replace the header in your XLSX file with the corrected names.

Answer (score 0):

Using this .xlsx file:

[image]

I used the library `openxlsx`. Using the `read.xlsx` function I got the following dataframe:

```
     a.long.col.name yet.another.second.column
1               a                         1
2               b                         2
3               c                         3
4               d                         4
```

`read.xlsx` also contains options to select rows and columns from the excel sheet:

```
read.xlsx('C:/Users/<username>/Documents/so_query.xlsx',
      rows  = 2:5,
      cols = 2)
```

Gives the following dataframe:

```
  1
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest one-liner is to add this to your `read_excel` call:

```
, .name_repair = function(col){ gsub(" ", "_", col) }
```

As in:

```
data <- read_excel(path = excel_file,
                  .name_repair = function(col){ gsub(" ", "_", col) } )
```

In this way `.name_repair` applies on the fly a simple function that uses `gsub` to replace in each `col` the space (`" "`) with an underscore (`"_"`).